# Javascript closure - binding value instead of reference

Tags: javascript, closures

The below example was taken from the book, "Javascript: The good parts". The author says that the helper function returns a function that binds to the **current value** of `var i`.

Can anyone explain what makes it to bind the VALUE instead of REFERENCE of `var i`, because `helper` function is a closure to `add_the_handler` function and should only see the reference of `var i`:

```
var add_the_handlers = function (nodes) {
   var helper = function (i) {
      return function (e) {
        alert(i);
      };
    };
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i += 1) {
       nodes[i].onclick = helper(i);
    }
};
```

Comment: The *i* variable in the 

    function (e) {
       alert(i);
    };

function is referenced to the local *i* variable in the *helper* function, instead of *i* variable in the *add_the_handlers* function.

Comment: This post/answer will be helpful (on pass by reference vs. value): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value/6605700#6605700

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you were to say:

```
nodes[i].onclick = function(){ alert(i) };
```

The function would not have it's own copy of `i` because `i` is not declared within the scope of the function.

To help you see this better I've modified your above code:

```
var add_the_handlers = function (nodes) {
    var helper = function(t) {
      // t is in the scope of "helper"
      return function(e){
        // e is in the scope of this anonymous function
        // and is not used
        alert(t);
      };
    };

    // Variables declared here are in the scope of "add_the_handlers"
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i += 1) {
       nodes[i].onclick = helper(i);
    }
};
```

In the "real world" you'll often see code like the above shortened to look like this:

```
var add_the_handlers = function(nodes){
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
       nodes[i].onclick = (function(i){ return function(e){ alert(i); }; })(i);
};
```

Comment: I believe, you should return a function like this,

`nodes[i].onclick = (function(i){ return function(e){alert(i);} })(i);`

Answer (score 1):

You pass the *current value* of `i` into the function `helper`. Inside that function the variable `i`, a (confusingly named) parameter to the function, is *different from any other `i`*. The closure returned thus binds to *that particular `i`* (really the [[scope]] which contains that `i`, but...).

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess: `i` is a primitive, so it's always accessed by value, and not by reference.

Comment: Nope, not at all :) It's not about object mutability, but rather about variable resolving. A new variable [[scope]] in JavaScript is only created with a new function declaration.