# Passing by value instead by reference to JavaScript closure - any non-wrapping technique?

Tags: javascript, closures

Variables passed to closure by reference. This code:

```
var figs = ['circle', 'square'];
for (var i in figs) {
    var fig = figs[i];
    document.getElementById(fig).addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        console.log(fig);
    }, false);
}
```

always log last array element even you click to *circle* (*square*, last value of *fig* variable).

In order to bind actual value of *fig* variable I use wrapping in function call (so intermediate closure  hold loop value):

```
var figs = ['circle', 'square'];
for (var i in figs) {
    var fig = figs[i];
    document.getElementById(fig).addEventListener("click", (function(fig) {
        return function(e) {
            console.log(fig);
        }
    })(fig), false);
}
```

Is that possible to avoid wrapping-function in order to pass by value?

**UPDATE** related questions and answers:

- [Javascript closure - binding value instead of reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728653/javascipt-closure-binding-value-instead-of-reference)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/518069/173149

Comment: This is not an issue of how values are passed to functions. JavaScript is **always** pass-by-value.  The issue here is the *scope* of variables, and specifically that new scopes are only created by function calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

However, you can make your code a bit nicer, by taking the code that produces the inner function out of the loop:

```
var figs = ['circle', 'square'];
function createFigHandler(fig) {
    return function(e) {
        console.log(fig);
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < figs.length; i++) {
    var fig = figs[i];
    document.getElementById(fig).addEventListener("click", createFigHandler(fig), false);
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lonesomeday/bqXAM/2/)

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! It really look better! +1

Comment: And he should be using shouldn't be using a `for-in` loop on arrays.

Comment: @0x499602D2 That's a very good point. Code edited to reflect this.

Comment: @lonesomeday You've got the for loop mixed up. Should be `for (var i = 0; i < fis.length; ++i)`

Comment: @gavenkoa The `for-in` should be avoided for arrays only. You only use it if you want to iterate over the key-value pairs of an object.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Oh, um, yes. What a twit I am. :-(

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `bind` and pass an object that encapsulates the variables you need. Then you can make use of `this.fig` inside the handler to reference your figure.

```
document.getElementById(fig).addEventListener("click", (function(e) {
     console.log(this.fig);
}).bind({ fig: fig }), false);
```

You can also bind a primitive value directly, however it will be wrapped in it's respective object wrapper e.g. `Number` for a number, `String` for a string, etc.

```
document.getElementById(fig).addEventListener("click", (function(e) {
    //this will be the same as new String(fig)
}).bind(fig), false);
```

Comment: Great technique! Especially for in-lining anonymous functions. It save one level of code indent! +1